# What other giants are there in 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

I'm looking into building a campaign involving the giants going at war. But I'm looking for diverse bunch of giants, so the party does not keep fighting the same type over and over again. Going through several books I've been able to find the following giants thus far:

- Cloud, Fire, Frost, Hill, Stone and Storm Giants (MM 1, p.119)

  - Three additional types of Frost Giant in Frostburn (p. 133)
- Forest, Mountain, Ocean and Sun Giants (MM2, p. 109)
- Death, Eldritch and Sand Giants (MM3, p. 54)
- Craa'ghoran Giants (MM4, p. 60)
- Bog and Shadow Giants (Fiend Folio, p. 81)
- Fog and Phaerlin Giants (Monsters of Faerûn, p. 50)

Note that I'm looking for "true" giants mentioned in the rulls as a Giant, *whatever*, and not for creatures such as fomorians who are giant-blooded, but not full-on giant. Did I miss anything else, or are these eighteen types all there are in 3.5e?

Comment: Not really a big enough answer to make it an actual answer, but you could turn any of those into undead ones following a Lich giant to mix it up.

Comment: The only way I can see this question being answered is with a big Community Wiki where everyone lists giants they found. That’s not a good answer, and it’s a strong sign this isn’t a good question for Stack Exchange to answer. I know of two you missed (Jungle and Primordial from *Secrets of Xen’drik*), but that doesn’t seem like a complete answer to me – and I’m not really inclined to dig through the entire 3.5 library looking for giants.

Comment: You can use http://monsterfinder.dndrunde.de/ to search for either monsters that are giant type, or have giant in the name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My old link didn't work, but [wotc's 3.5 lists](https://web.archive.org/web/20211218141717/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/lists) are still up. If you click on Monster, type giant in the search, the sort by type, you'll get something like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915110920/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/monsters&tablefilter=giant&tablesort=4). Unfortunately, you'll have to filter down "true" giants from there.

Here's a list with the creatures you are looking for:

> - Abyssal Giant – EDP
> - Bog Giant – FF
> - Cloud Giant – MM
> - Craa'ghoran Giant – MM4
> - Death Giant – MM3
> - Dusk Giant, Least – HH
> - Dusk Giant, Lesser – HH
> - Dusk Giant, Greater – HH
> - Eldritch Giant – MM3
> - Eldritch Confessor Giant – MM3
> - Fire Giant – MM
> - Draconic Fire Giant – Dr
> - Fog Giant – Mon
> - Forest Giant – MM2
> - Frost Giant – MM
> - Frost Giant Jarl – MM
> - Frost Mauler Giant – Fr
> - Frost Spiritspeaker Giant – Fr
> - Frost Tundra Scout Giant – Fr
> - Hill Giant – MM
> - Jungle Giant – SX
> - Mountain Giant – MM2
> - Ocean Giant – MM2
> - Phaerlin Giant – Mon
> - Sand Giant – MM3
> - Sand Champion Giant – MM3
> - Shadow Giant – FF
> - Stone Giant – MM
> - Stone Elder Giant – MM
> - Storm Giant – MM
> - Sun Giant – MM2
> - Totem Giant – MoI

22 in total, with 10 additional variations.

Here's a list of all other creatures with the Giant type:

> - Bladerager Troll – MM5
> - Cave Troll – MM3
> - Common Oni – OA
> - Crystalline Troll – MM3
> - Ettin – MM
> - Fell Troll – Una
> - Fensir – FF
> - Firbolg – MM2
> - Fomorian – MM2
> - Forest Troll – MM3
> - Geriviar – MM3
> - Giant – MM2
> - Giant Cyclops – ShS
> - Go-Zu Oni – OA
> - Greater Cyclops – DD
> - Half-Giant – XPH
> - Half-Ogre (Player Race) – RD
> - Half-Troll Barbazu – FF
> - Half-Troll Template – FF
> - Ice Troll – Una
> - Ken-Kuni – MM5
> - Ken-Li – MM5
> - Ken-Sun – MM5
> - Lesser Cyclops – DD
> - Maur (Hunched Giant) – Und
> - Me-Zu Oni – OA
> - Mountain Troll – MM3
> - Ogre – MM
> - Ogre Barbarian – MM
> - Ogre Guard Thrall – MM4
> - Ogre Mage – MM
> - Ogre Scout – MM4
> - Ogre Tempest – MM4
> - Ogre, Skullcrusher – MM3
> - Ogre, Skullcrusher Sergeant – MM3
> - Primordial Giant (Template) – SX
> - Rakka – FF
> - Taer – Una
> - Troll – MM
> - Troll Hunter – MM
> - Wang-Liang – OA
> - Wasteland Troll – Sa

Comment: Oh, ***awesome.*** This is one of those rare answers that *saves* a question (at least to me). By the way, [this link goes directly to the table, sorted by Type](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/monsters&tablesort=4)

Comment: I have a list of the creatures with the Giant type, sorted alphabetically. Would you mind if I edited that into your answer?

Comment: No. Sounds like an improvement.

Comment: They have a Cave Troll.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I have taken the liberty of splitting your list in two: one half with what I was looking for and one half with the rest. One question though: it mentions Giant (MM2), but I cannot find this entry in the book. What is the idea behind this one? Or is this just the type?